# Catalina's ´top´does not show vsize

Tags: terminal

So I'm running `top -stats pid,command,kprvt,vsize,rprvt` and I get the following output:

```
Processes: 314 total, 2 running, 312 sleeping, 1827 threads                            13:05:41
Load Avg: 5.02, 4.32, 4.20  CPU usage: 22.82% user, 11.76% sys, 65.41% idle
SharedLibs: 173M resident, 56M data, 14M linkedit.
MemRegions: 124907 total, 1560M resident, 62M private, 649M shared.
PhysMem: 8082M used (3189M wired), 109M unused.
VM: 3244G vsize, 1987M framework vsize, 287575527(192) swapins, 300917960(0) swapouts.
Networks: packets: 13403531/8415M in, 10226281/3149M out.
Disks: 29569952/1427G read, 17952018/1367G written.

PID               COMMAND                     KPRVT           VSIZE           RPRVT
441               Terminal                    N/A             N/A             N/A
62759             com.apple.WebKit            N/A             N/A             N/A
235               WindowServer                N/A             N/A             N/A
0                 kernel_task                 N/A             N/A             N/A
147               hidd                        N/A             N/A             N/A
2686              com.apple.WebKit            N/A             N/A             N/A
63156             top                         N/A             N/A             N/A
42514             plugin-container            N/A             N/A             N/A
37592             firefox                     N/A             N/A             N/A
535               Safari                      N/A             N/A             N/A
581               com.apple.WebKit            N/A             N/A             N/A
62714             WebexHelper                 N/A             N/A             N/A
91                RTProtectionDaem            N/A             N/A             N/A
427               FrontendAgent               N/A             N/A             N/A
```

However Brew's `htop` can display virtual memory just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MacOS to show those values, you must include the `-r` parameter.

Add it to the command line you are using:

Eg:  `top -r -stats pid,command,kprvt,vsize,rprvt`

Comment: Thank you @Prado! `-r      Traverse and report the memory object map for each process.` I wouldn't have guessed it from the description. Thanks again!